# Magento2 not working, shows 404 Not Found

Tags: php, apache, magento, xampp

[This is my browser output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bgUx.png) Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.54 (Win64) OpenSSL/1.1.1p PHP/8.1.12 Server at localhost Port 80

I try to set up Magento in my localhost through XAMPP.

I used this code to install Magento through the composer

```
php bin/magento setup:install --base-url="http://localhost/magento2/" --db-host="localhost" --db-name="magento_2.4.5" --db-user="root" --admin-firstname="admin" --admin-lastname="admin" --admin-email="user@example.com" --admin-user="admin" --admin-password="admin123" --language="en_US" --currency="USD" --timezone="America/Chicago" --use-rewrites="1" --backend-frontname="admin"
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @KargWare I upload it.